# Find earliest time for k empty group

Tags: algorithm

I was asked this question in an interview recently, I still cannot come up with a solution.

There are N slots in a river. An array P is given where each index denotes the time at which the stone at that position will appear. I have to come up with an algorithm to find the earliest time at which there will be K contiguous *empty slots*. For E.G.

```
N = 5

P = [2,5,1,4,3]

K = 2

Initially: [0,0,0,0,0] 

All the slots are empty.

Now at:

Time t = 1, second stone will appear --> [0,1,0,0,0]

Time t = 2, fifth stone will appear --> [0,1,**0,0**,1]

Time t = 3, first stone will appear --> [1,1,0,0,1]

Time t = 4, fourth stone will appear --> [1,1,0,1,1]

Time t = 5, third stone will appear --> [1,1,1,1,1]
```

So the answer for above case is `2`, because at time `2` there are (k = 2) continuous empty slots.

Comment: So what exactly is the question?

Comment: To find the earliest time at which there will be K contiguous empty slots

Comment: That would be `2`, as you already wrote in your question.

Comment: Sorry if it was not clear I edited the question, I have to come up with an algorithm for solving the above problem

Comment: what is the expected time complexity required?

Comment: @CodeHunter: (NLogN) worst case time complexity and (N) space complexity

Comment: one more things: the `p` array given would be composed of continuous integer, right? (i.e. from 1 to `n`)

Comment: @CodeHunter: Yes right.

Comment: cool. I came up with one solution, yet to verify it for all edge cases: here it goes: form a bitonic array from the given array such that it is a combination of strictly increasing and strictly decreasing elements: for e.g. in your case, it would be `1 5 2 4 3`. Notice how `1 and 5`,`2 and 4` are placed and how they are part of individual strictly increasing and decreasing sequences respectively. store their time occurrences as well.  Find at any point, if the difference between two consecutive elements is equal to k+1. Report that time interval after checking if it is a valid one.

Comment: (continue to previous comment) I am trying to figure how we can restrict the space complexity to the use of single array here rather than creating a separate array for storing time occurrences. Let me know if you can find out one!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155207/discussion-between-shubham-and-codehunter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found the O(n) time complexity and O(n) space complexity solution on leetcode. To explain briefly:

> The idea is to use an array `days[]` to record each position flower's
>   blooming day. That means `days[i]` is the blooming day of the flower in
>   position `i+1`. We just need to find a subarray `days[left, left+1,...,left+k-1, right]` which satisfies: for any `i = left+1,..., left+k-1`, we can have `days[left] < days[i] && days[right] < days[i]`. Then, the result is `max(days[left], days[right])`.

Here is the link to the exact solution: https://discuss.leetcode.com/topic/104771/java-c-simple-o-n-solution

Answer (score 5):

Every time you add a stone you're basically dividing a sequence of contiguous empty slots (zeros) in two parts. You can use this idea to construct a binary tree where each node represents an interval (of zeros and ones - stones and empty spaces) and each *leaf* node represents an interval of *zeros only*.

To add a stone you find the appropriate leaf node (corresponding interval must include the position for your new stone) and add new leaf nodes - for the intervals on the left and on the right vs the stone you add. At this moment you can check the length of those new intervals and stop if you found one with required length.

The only problem here is that the tree may become unbalanced so to get O(nlogn) worst case you should apply some technics to balance the tree as it grows - red-black tree or something like that - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree

Answer (score 1):

Note, in inner loop P items to the right of `i` position can be safely omitted. However, this is still O(n^2)

```
    int K = 2;
    int[] P = { 2, 5, 1, 4, 3 };
    int N = P.Length;

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
        {
            if (Math.Abs(P[j] - P[i] + 1) == K)
            {
                return i + 1; //+1 because we iterate from 0 | this is the ans (time) 
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use BIT tree to solve this problem. You want exactly k slots to be empty
so let's assume that occurred at the time i.

```
a=p[i]-k-1;
b=p[i]+k+1;
```

Array T tells whether stone is at index i or not.

Now all entries between index a and p[i] or b and p[i] in array T should be zero. This can be checked by making use of range queries I prefer BIT tree but segment tree can also be used.